# Why does NaN = !NaN return true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nan, assignment-operator

NaN is one of those vestigial implementations of questionable origins, but for the most part *I get it*. However, I typed this into a Node prompt today and couldn't really make sense of it...

```
NaN = !NaN
> true
```

Is this simply returning the evaluated result of `!NaN`? This makes sense, but I'm surprised that there's not an error when attempting to assign NaN to another value.

**Note:** this question is about this specific syntax structure; there are a lot of questions related to NaN and isNaN out there but I couldn't find an answer after googling. Thanks to Ori Drori for the [best answer thus far](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41316867/3399115).

```js
console.log(NaN = !NaN);
```

Comment: @pvg doesn't seem like a duplicate of that. There is no comparison of NaN to anything here.

Comment: @pvg I did search before posting this and didn't see an answer for the specific question I was asking.

Comment: @MartinSmith you're right, I misread the question, removed the flag. This one is a lot easier but harder to pin down a dupe in the sea of  related answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are assigning `true` to `NaN` instead of comparing `NaN` to `!NaN` using `===` or `==`, so the operation returns the assigned value -> `true`. Javascript ignores this assignment silently because [`NaN` is read only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

```js
console.log(NaN = true);

// NaN hasn't changed
console.log(NaN);
```

If you'll add `use strict` to your code, JS will throw a [**read only**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only) error instead:

```js
'use strict';
NaN = true;
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! More reason that I should be using Strict Mode.

Comment: Strict mode rules :)

Answer (score 4):

`=` is the asignment operator. 
`==` and `===` are comparison operators.

```
NaN == !NaN
false
NaN === !NaN
false
```

Perhaps more surprisingly:

```
NaN  == NaN
false
NaN  === NaN
false
```

For more about NaN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Answer (score 2):

Try running Javascript in a `strict` mode to avoid most of the problems.

NaN, null, false, "", null, undefined, 0 etc they are considered as falsy values (remember `falsy` !== `false`) in javascript, no matter you use a `strict` mode or not.

```
// 'use strict';

console.log(!NaN);       // true
console.log(!null);      // true
console.log(!false);     // true
console.log(!"");        // true
console.log(!null);      // true
console.log(!undefined); // true
console.log(!0);         // true
```

It is true in Python as well, except for NaN. For example,

```
print(not False)        # True
print(not None)         # True
print(not float("NaN")) # False
print(not "")           # True
print(not 0)            # True
```

**Source of confusion**
When we use multiple languages sometimes it can be a source of confusion.

For example,

In Python `'cat' in ['fat', 'cat', 'rat', 'hat']` returns True.

In Javascript `'cat' in ['fat', 'cat', 'rat', 'hat']` (exactly the same piece of code) returns false no matter you use a `strict` mode or not.

In Python `print(not [])` returns True.

In Javascript `console.log(![]);` returns false.

This is one of the reasons why I always love to use debuggers, REPL etc no matter how simple the code is.

Answer (score 1):

Using `=` operator, you assign the value to a variable. However, what you don't know is by doing that, it returns the value of what is being assigned. Typing:

```
v = 1
```

in a JavaScript REPL will display 1, because that is what was assigned to `v`. So, doing:

```
NaN = !NaN
```

Will assign the opposite value of `NaN` to `NaN` itself. Since `NaN` in boolean is `false`, then `!NaN` in boolean must be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is really weird: When you write

```
NaN = true  // true
```

which you basically do in your statement, you get "true". This is the same behavior as when you write

```
a = true  // true
```

where the right side of the assignment is returned. But if you add `var` and write

```
var a = true  // undefined
```

then nothing is returned. Also if you replace NaN with an expression that evaluates to NaN, for example

```
1/"a" = true  // error!
```

then you get a ReferenceError. I recommend to never use the return values of assignments. The behavior is inconclusive and your code will be hard to read. You can enable "strict mode" to check this for you.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for clarifying!